# How to align last row to the left with CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="region-table-container">
    <div class="region-table-value"</div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.region-table-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:400px;
    }

    .region-table-value {
        width: 32%;
        color: #7f8585;
        font-size: $font-size-x-small;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 26px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

and the result is that the last row (NY / FL) is not aligned to the left as the rest of the names (see image).
[image: last row is not aligned to the left]

How to fix this please?

Thanks.

Comment: use display:inline-block

Comment: Please provide complete code or create a fiddle.

Comment: How is created that table? Looks more like a estructure issue than an aligment issue.

Comment: post your complete code. With your pasted fragment it works well. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjwNxq

Comment: let me see your code ??

Comment: I pasted all I have got. The table is created when I add 'display:inline-block' to child element.  I am trying to have 3 columns at most. Its strange that it works in the codepen sample.....